# How to efficiently remove words from a string vector of certain length

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am currently trying to work with a vector of strings, and need to be able to efficiently remove elements that are not of a certain string length.

I was thinking about doing something like `vector.erase(remove_if(etc))`, however I can't use lambdas due to using C++98, and if I were to create a predicate it would need parameters because the length is a variable and can change based on user input.

Can anyone provide a basic solution to this with these restrictions?

Comment: Do some research about *functor objects*. It's have been possible since well before C++ was standardized.

Comment: `remove_if()` doesn't do anything magical, you can just iterate the vector yourself and remove any elements you want.

Comment: <algorithm>find_if  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/?kw=algorithm

Comment: Q: "Can anyone provide a basic solution to this with these restrictions?"  A:  Not just anyone.

Answer (score 3):

It's not like in C++03 you didn't have functors, they were just 10x more awkward to use...

```
// important: outside from any function
// (local types weren't allowed as template parameters) 
struct size_mismatcher {
    size_t size;
    size_mismatcher(size_t size) : size(size) {}
    bool operator()(const std::string& s) { return s.size() != size; }
};

// in your function:
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                         size_mismatcher(target_size)),
          vec.end());
```

Or just do it the classic way:

```
size_t wp = 0;
for(size_t rp = 0, n = vec.size(); rp != n; ++rp) {
    if(vec[rp].size() == target_size) {
        vec[wp] = vec[rp];
        ++wp;
    }
}
vec.resize(wp);
```

Comment: Could you explain how your second way works? I could swear it doesn't work properly, I'm confused. https://onlinegdb.com/SygsRxatM

Comment: @Zebrafish: sorry, I shouldn't really write code on the phone in train :-) the two lines were inverted; still, I fixed it with a clearer version of the algorithm (and more efficient with nontrivial types), where it's easier to see how it works.